# how can I get accidently deleted Key for Android applications

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Accidentally I deleted Key for Android applications from google console.I am talking about android key using for map display.Is there any way to get it back from console.
I try another key for android, but it not working.

Comment: Which Key? There are many keys>...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the key you seek is the Google API key.

If so, log on to [Google Developers Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and on the left panel select `APIs & Auth` and then click `Credentials`.

You should see a key under `Public API access`

Good luck